# Accessing Listview inside ItemTemplete of list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to access listview inside another listview in c# page so that I can bind datasource of the inner listview.

Below is the asp code.

```
     <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="itemListView">
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:Panel CssClass="twelve columns" ID="outerPanel" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="twelve columns" ID="row">

                                            <h4 runat="server"><a href='Itemdetails.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Id")%>'><%#Eval("Name")%></a></h4>
                                            <dl class="tabs  .three-up" >
                                                <dd class="active"><a href='#accepted<%#Eval("Id")%>'>Accepted Requests</a></dd>
                                                <dd><a href='#open<%#Eval("Id")%>'>Open Requests</a></dd>
                                                <dd><a href='#rejected<%#Eval("Id")%>'>Rejected Requests</a></dd>
                                            </dl>
                                            <ul class="tabs-content">
                                                <li class="active" id='accepted<%#Eval("Id")%>Tab'>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="abc" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="innerlistview"></asp:ListView>
                                                </li>
                                                <li id='open<%#Eval("Id")%>Tab'>This is simple tab 2s content.</li>
                                                <li id='rejected<%#Eval("Id")%>Tab'>This is simple tab 3s content.</li>
                                            </ul> 
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </asp:Panel>

                                </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:ListView>
```

Can you please tell me that how I can access it?

Comment: Also, I only see one ListView in the code you've shown.

Comment: Apologies, I have innerlistview and tried to access this listview in c# code, but compiler does not recognize this listview as it is inside another listview.

Comment: Please look at the rendered post here, and edit your code so that it displays.

Comment: Amandeep, Did you try my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

In the itemListView create a event handler for itemdatabound. Now to access the inner listview use the following code.

```
protected void itemListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListView innerlistview= (ListView) e.Item.FindControl("innerlistview");

        innerlistview.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        innerlistview.DataBind();

    }
}
```

I added a SQL datasource and was able to bind data.

I just added the below code also

```
   <LayoutTemplate>
    <ul ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
        <li ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
        <div style="">
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
```

Also on the ASPX page use this

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="itemListView" onitemdatabound="itemListView_ItemDataBound">
```

Comment: On using the above code it is giving me error :  No overload for 'itemListView_ItemDataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' compile time. I tried using   public void itemListView_ItemDataBound(object sender,  EventArgs e ) but then Item is not identified as type inside the method.

Comment: This above error is because used ondatabound="itemListView_ItemDataBound" intead of onitemdatabound="itemListView_ItemDataBound"